# Convert NSRange contents to NSString?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsstring, nsrange

I am working on a Cocoa Mac OSX app, and I am wondering if it is possible to present the contents of an `NSRange` found by:

```
NSRange range;
range.location = 4;
range.length = 4;
```

as an `NSString`?

*e.g.* in the example above, if I had a string with contents **"abcdefgh"**, presenting the contents of the above range as a string would give **"efgh"**. Is this possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Code:**

```
NSString *string = @"abcdefgh";

NSRange range;
range.location = 4;
range.length = 4;

NSString *subString = [string substringWithRange:range];

NSLog(@"%@",subString);
```

**Output:**

```
efgh
```

Comment: Thank you so much I had never heard of the substringWithRange method!

Answer (score 2):

Try the method substringWithRange from NSString.

```
NSString* original = @"abcdefgh";
NSLog(@"Substring: %@", [original substringWithRange:range]);
```